# Lord Hailsham and Learned Hand - Two Addresses

Tags: constitutional-law, england-and-wales, legal-research, history

I've been reading some broad and general books on constitutional and public law of England and Wales. A number of works are often cited, e.g. Lord Bingham's *Rule of law*, Bagehot's *The English Constitution*, Dicey's *Law of the Constitution* etc. However, I've also come across a number of shorter essays and addresses which seem to be rather difficult to get my hands on. The first is Lord Hailsham's 1976 Richard Dimbleby Lecture titled *Elective Dictatoship*, apparently popularising the phrase. The second is Learned Hand's address marking the 250th anniversary of the Supreme Judicial Court of Massachusetts in November 1942 where he talks about the spirit of moderation.

The only sources I can find for these are out-of-print books and even outer-of-print magazines which cost a small fortune.

Does anyone know of a more readily available source for these two addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try worldcat.org. It knows the catalog of most libraries in the world. You look up a book or periodical and enter your location. I’m in CA and I found four libraries that have The Listener within 25 miles of me. Wikipedia references a 1976 issue for one of the items.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I put in Berlin and found at least three libraries that have the periodical. Less luck if you are in Paris. The closest ones are in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

For *Elective Dictatorship* you could try visiting, or if that's not feasible, ordering a copy from the [British Library](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?tabs=moreTab&ct=display&fn=search&doc=BLL01009428803&indx=1&recIds=BLL01009428803&recIdxs=0&elementId=0&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&frbrVersion=&frbg=&&dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A%28BLCONTENT%29&vl(2084770704UI0)=any&tb=t&vid=BLVU1&mode=Basic&srt=rank&tab=local_tab&dum=true&vl(freeText0)=0563172541&dstmp=1630494984790).

And there's also the [Bodleian Library](https://solo.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/primo-explore/fulldisplay?docid=oxfaleph016011362&context=L&vid=SOLO&lang=en_US&search_scope=LSCOP_ALL&adaptor=Local%20Search%20Engine&tab=local&query=any,contains,Dimbleby%20Lecture%201976&offset=0). Details on how to join are [here](https://www.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/join-the-libraries#/) if you're not already a member.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those options when I get a chance to. I'm stuck on the continent, you see.